# Why my mobile phone cannot connect to my laptop through WLAN?

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking, symbian

I created a temporary network using my laptop (Windows 7), but my mobile phone (Symbian S60) could not connect to it (the status of the network is always waiting), either in public mode or with WEP authentication.

Another laptop can connect to this network and access the Internet through the shared Internet connection, and my mobile phone can connect to a public WiFi access point normally.

I chose "Ad-hoc" as the WLAN network mode in my phone's control panel, and other settings (IP addresses, security settings, etc) seemed to be correct.

Comment: How exactly does the ad hoc network get Internet access?

Comment: Are you manually defining a IP? Automatic is usually best in this situation. Don't bother with WEP until you get publc working - from personal experience Symbian (S60/^3) phones are rather picky about ad-hoc WEP security and don't support ad-hoc WPA/WPA2 at all.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz My laptop can access the Internet through a LAN, then I create the temporary wireless network and chose to share the Internet connection at the end of creation.